# Singularities of $Spec(Sym^* E^{\vee})$ for $E$ a coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, coherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be a smooth complex algebraic variety, and $\mathscr{E}$ a torsion-free coherent sheaf on $X$.

> Which type of singularities can the total space $\mathrm{Tot}(\mathscr{E}):=\underline{\mathrm{Spec}}_X(\mathrm{Sym}^{\bullet} \mathscr{E}^{\vee})$ have (if any)?

Comment: You might have realized this already but it must be smooth over every smooth codimension 1 point this suggests that singularities might have to be of codimension > generic rank $\mathcal{E}$ + 1

Comment: You might look at Section 2 of "The Kodaira Dimension of Spaces of Rational Curves on Low Degree Hypersurfaces".  That section relates various measures of singularities to the properties of the stratification of $X$ by the rank of the torsion-free sheaf.